# How to say those mouth-watering Chinese dishes names in Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary, word-requests, culture

Chinese food is delicious. For example, beef noodles (牛肉面) is one of my favorites. Fried noodle (炒面) and fried rice with shrimp（虾仁炒饭）are also yummy.

Q: How to say other mouth-watering Chinese dishes in Chinese? (What are other favorite food names in a restaurant menu.)

Q: What are the proper sentences to order food in a Chinese restaurant?

Comment: mouth-watering = 令人垂涎的

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. The first question was actually asking what are other or favorite food names in a restaurant menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list, you may referred to it and choose some from it

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_dishes

some typical dishes are as follows

English Traditional Chinese Simplified Chinese  Pinyin  Notes

Baozi   包子  包子  bāozǐ   : steamed buns with fillings

Dim sum 點心  点心  diǎnxīn : a staple of Cantonese cuisine

Guotie  鍋貼  锅贴  guōtiē  :fried dumplings

Jiaozi  餃子  饺子  jiǎozǐ  :steamed or boiled dumplings

Mantou  饅頭  馒头  mántóu  :steamed buns

Wonton  餛飩 / 雲吞 馄钝 / 云吞 húntún / yúntūn :sphere-shaped dumplings usually served boiled in broth or deep-fried

Xiaolongbao 小籠包 小笼包 xiǎolóngbāo :soup dumplings, a specialty of Shanghai cuisine

Zongzi  粽子  粽子  zòngzǐ  :glutinous rice wrapped in bamboo leaves, usually with a savory or sweet filling

sample sentences:

1. 來一盤(lai-yi-pan)  餃子(jiao-zi)， 麻煩你(ma-fan-ni)。
2. 給我一籠(gei-wo-yi-long)  小籠包(xiao-long-bao)， 謝謝你(xie-xie-ni)。
3. 我點一份(wo-dian-yi-fen)  餛飩(hun-tun)，有勞你了(you-lao-ni-le)。

Comment: 粽子 are definitely not mouth-watering

Answer (score 2):

> Q: How to say other mouth-watering Chinese dishes in Chinese?

In Chinese you can say something like “垂涎欲滴”、“垂涎三尺”……This means foods are too nice for you to eat so that you are now drooling.

> Q:What are the proper sentences to order food in a Chinese restaurant?

Some steps of ordering dishes, you can watch the torturial of Chinese video: [点菜](http://kuailehanyu.cntv.cn/20100619/100042.shtml)，[幻灯片教学版](http://wenku.baidu.com/link?url=6-6I-J9fVP3wSNQKmL5dXhGmDJteKKG6nCidVjAJVBHjV99gbybOpu_8Ne_fnOPSC7kyA7pTOHBNaf1w3vDwOb8gS6XIlshKypjaBdpL3vG)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And sorry for the ambiguity. The first question was actually asking what are other or favorite food names in a restaurant menu